# Reporting operations per time interval in C#

Tags: c#, time-series

I have a series of events which may number several hundred per second at peak times. I want to be able to track and report the number of events per interval (e.g. last 5 minutes, last hour, last 24 hours, last 7 days). What's are some options for tracking this type of data in C#

Comment: What kind of events are you talking about ?

Comment: Well, as an example, let's say I'm receiving plain text messages of the "Hello World!" type. I just want to know how to report how many messages I've received over the given time periods.

Comment: And how are these messages being received ? Do you have an EventHandler that reacts on some events or are you receiving strings that are being stored in a file ?

Comment: I'm receiving these messages via a network stream. Right now, they're being stored in memory, pending a more efficient way to manage this.

Comment: Does my answer not provide the tools necessary to solve this problem? If you log all events as they come over the network you can, when needed, analyze the logs and output the event frequency as per your problem specification.

Comment: I don't think someone can give you an answer without knowing some implementation details. I don't know your experience with C# (whether you are a pro or a newbe) but in general logging simply means to store something (your incoming events) in a separate place under specified conditions (time interval, type of items to log, etc). So if you have a stream that gives you these messages I would say you`ll trivially have to read from this stream and store the read items in some data structure and/or write it into a file.

Comment: Well the content of the message is irrelevant. I'm not looking to log every incoming message with a timestamp and then sort / filter that way. I know I could do that, but that would be incredibly inefficient.

Comment: First of all, I don't think you need to store the message, just the timestamp. I mean, you care only about the time the message was received right? And I really think you'd be hard pressed to find something more straightforward than this solution. Besides, why do premature optimization? Try implementing the solution then talk efficiency.

Comment: You can accumulate message counts into 5 minute histogram slots: 00:00, 00:05, ... .  Then summarize those counts as needed.  Strictly speaking that does not give you the _last_ 5 minutes, but it may be acceptable for your needs.  The data can age out, e.g. keep 5 minute counts for 6 hours, one hour counts for 24 hours, 24 hour counts for 60 days.

Comment: Well if you only need to know the number of messages received - why don't you simply increment a counter ?

Comment: @Marc - that won't allow him to analyze it by intervals. Say he increments the counter 50 times in one day, that doesn't tell him anything about the last 5 minutes or 3 hours ago.

Comment: @MichaelDmitryAzarkevich of course it does. He simply has to deal with the time passed. I'll formulate an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Having all that in mind what I know of you problem so far I would simply count the number of received events with an integer variable or a long variable respectively.

To count the events within a particular period of time without having a timestamp of your items at hand you have to decide for a time granularity a priori and track the incoming events according to the resulting time frames. To measure time passed you may utilize a concurrent thread.

That means if you decide for a granularity of 5 minutes you would have to implement a thread that maintains one counter. This counter get incremented on every incoming event. Every 5 minutes the thread would store the current counter in a list and reset it to 0.
After say 60 minutes you would have a List of 12 items reflecting the number of messages received. With that list you could handle queries like

- How many events in the first 5 minutes ?
- How many events in the first 10 minutes ?
- How many events in the period of 5 minutes after 15 minutes of receiving.
- ...

From then on it's only a matter of interpreting the counters collected and stored into the list over time.

---

**On the other hand** if you want to be able to query time intervals of any granularity (meaning to decide posteriori for what time intervals you want to know how many events have been received) I think you have no other choice as to maintain a data structure with timestamps.

So for every single event you would have to store the time it has been received in order to answer the above mentioned queries. If you receive hundreds of events per second that might not be a good idea.

Comment: This would, of course, work if it's OK for the events to be of finite granularity but logging can work at any granularity, decided on the fly. All of this, of course, depends on the actual problem parameters.

Comment: @Michael But if you would like to filter a log (which actually does not exits in the context of this question/answer) with any granularity of time intervals I see no other choice than using a timestamp for every received event that gets stored. If the OP receives hundreds of events per second that could really be of less performance.

Comment: I totally agree, the right answer depends on what's more important - performance vs granularity. Both our answers *could* be correct, it just depends on what's more important to the OP.

Comment: @Michael yes I absolutely agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to assign a timestamp to the event. I think you'll go ahead and process the events in any way. Thus you're likely to store the event and/or its data somehow. Just extend the data structure by a timestamp member and add a time stamp at the time the event occurs.
This way you can build your "incoming" statistics at some later point in time at some other point in your code. You can simply evaluate which events occured in certain time frames.

As a source for reasonable timestamps I'd suggest the `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` API. This should be able to deliver unique values when your maximum event rate is up to a few hundred per second. However timestamps don't have to have unique values when their purpose is solely to tell in which time frame they fall. When a higher resolution becomes neccessary a look at 
the `QueryPerformanceCounter()` API can be helpfull. A combination of the two APIs described here can lead to timestamp resolution **and** accuracy of a few microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

From the problem description I assume that you want to monitor your system performance, load and troughput. If that's so, I suppose you could use WMI for that.

I am sorry that I cannot provide more detailed information, but I think you can start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186147%28v=vs.80%29

Answer (score -1):

You have a two stage problem here -  logging the events and presenting them. If you keep track of all events for, say, the last month you could choose to show only those events that happened in the last 5 minutes, last 7 days or even something more complicated like "all events between 1 AM and 3 PM 12 days ago".

Some logging options for .NET can be found [here](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/). Good luck with your problem!